# Reminder for a specific time in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I need to write a python program that lets me set reminders for specific times, eg 'remember to take bins out at 2pm', but I can only work out setting a reminder for a certain length of time, not for a given time. I also need to be able to set multiple reminders for multiple times.
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a homework assignment, so you need to write the code yourself.

1. You know what time it is now.  You know when 2pm is.  How much time is there between now and 2pm?  Sleep for that long.
2. Keep a list of all pending alarms. Find the earliest alarm.  Remove it from the list.  Sleep until that alarm happens.  Repeat

You'll probably find Step 2 easier if you use an appropriate data structure like heapq or PriorityQueue.  But if the number of alarms is small, a list should do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following checks for any new reminders every seconds,
although, after reading Frank's answer, that would be a better solution,
and the best solution is to not use Python at all, and let the operating system manage this by creating a cron job or on Windows a scheduled task.

```
reminders = [
    # Put all of your reminders here
    ('2021-11-16 02:44:00', 'Take out the garbage'),
    ('2021-11-17 04:22:00', 'Another reminder')
]

from datetime import datetime
import time

# For performance reasons it's best to perform whatever computations we can before we go into our infinite loop
# In this case let's calculate all of the timestamps
reminders2 = {datetime.fromisoformat(reminder[0]).timestamp(): reminder[1] for reminder in reminders}

while True:
    now = time.time()
    for timestamp, reminder_msg in reminders2.items():
        if timestamp < now:
            print(reminder_msg)
            del reminders2[timestamp]
            # we're not in any hurry, instead of worrying about the consequences of deleting something from the same dictionary we are iterating over
            # we can just break and wait for the next go around of the while loop to finish checking the remaining reminders
            break
    time.sleep(1) # in seconds
```